# GetOrgChart - Organizational Chart image field

Tags: charts, organizational-chart

is it possible to remove or hide the image field from displaying in users details. Please refer on the image. Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqnzh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS

Here is an example with the latest version

```
[data-field-name=image]
{
  display:none;
}
```

[Hide data field by field name](http://codepen.io/getorgchart/pen/nlCas)